# Using ogrinfo to list all projection source of a database

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr, batch

I have to reproject all the layers from a database, but some of them are undefined and some are defined in a wrong projection. I would like to sort all those layers in a text file with their source projection and their path. I tried:

```
For /R %f in (*.tab) do ogrinfo -al -so %~dpnxf > list.txt
```

The fact is only the last layer return a result in the `list.txt`. Do you know why? Is there a more appropriate method to overcome that projection problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you might want to append (`>>`) the projection to `list.txt` and not assign (`>`), otherwise `list.txt` will be overwritten at each iteration of your for loop.

```
For /R %f in (*.tab) do ogrinfo -al -so %~dpnxf >> list.txt
```

Comment: reference for how redirect in a command shell works: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html